# Saving String[] to a bundle to be used when activity is recreated

Tags: android

When my activity is ran for the first time it downloads some url strings and sets them to.

a String list...

```
public   String [] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};
```

the imageUrl's inside are 4 url's that are downloaded and set to the variables..

When the activity is closed or destroyed, how can i save these url's to their variables so they wont be erased when the activity is destroyed?

Could i possible save it in a bundle and then onRestoreInstanceState pull them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save these strings during activity re-creation use the following method.

```
public String [] myRemoteImages = /* ... */;
private static final String KEY_URLS = "urls";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        myRemoteImages = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(KEY_URLS);
    }
 }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArray(KEY_URLS, myRemoteImages);
}
```

If you want to keep these string alive when your application is closed by user you'd better use `SharedPreferences`.

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called when the activity is restored. It means that this activity is recreating after configuration change or after a process containing this activity was killed and re-launched. So if you want to save a state before your app closes, use `onPause()`/`onResume()` methods to save and restore it.

Comment: SO should i do it the way you stated above? Becuase i tried it, once the app is killed, the methods above doesnt reload the strings[]

Comment: I want to be able to save the strings[] when the activity its killed.

Comment: You can save these strings to 'SharedPrefererences' when you get them or when they change. And in `onCreate()` for example you can try to load these strings. The main idea is not to wait until your app is killed because you won't be able to do anything in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If your activity is destroyed you would not be able to save data, but you can use SharedPreferences for example to save some datas like Strings:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref